# How to rotate the image using sensor manager azimuth value in android?

Tags: android, view, azimuth, sensormanager

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //accel
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);



        setContentView(R.layout.sample);
    }

    ///////////////// Basics
    /**
     * Called when the application is in the background
     */
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);

        //this is important because Android applications
        //do not close, they are in the background
        //so resources would be hogged otherwise
    }

    /**
     * Called when the application is started
     * or in the foreground again
     */
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor, rate);

    }

    //==================Accel=====================
    /**
     * Called when the values of the acceleration sensor changes
     * 
     * @param e Details about the change
     */
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent e) 
        {
            float azimuth=e.values[0];

                    Log.i("azimuth",String.valueOf(azimuth));


        }

        /**
         * Called when accuracy of the sensor is changed
         * 
         * @param sen Which sensor's accuracy changed
         * @param acc The new accuracy degree
         */
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sen, int acc) 
        {
        }
```

Here i am getting azimuth value using sensor manager.i want to know how to rotate imageview like compass  using azimuth value?can anyone give some idea ?how to use the OnDraw function here?
Without draw the circle or line inside OnDraw method?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can rotate an imageview:

```
Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
imageview.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
matrix.postRotate((float) -azimuth, imageview.getDrawable().getBounds().width()/2, 
imageview.getDrawable().getBounds().height()/2);            

imageview.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

For API 11+, there's an easy way:

```
arrow.setRotation((float) -azimuth);
```

You can check out this [blog](http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/create-our-android-compass.html) for the circle and line compass.

Hope this helps.